# Difference between different methods of putting data into session in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf-2

There are several methods  to get put Data into Session in JSF 2.0
For example:

> Making Bean Session Scoped
> (But I don't consider it a good practice; as I don't need all of the data to be in Session and need just selective info. to be part of a session scope)
> Using HttpSession object.
>
> Using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap.put("key", value)

I tried all of them in my test application;
Now, what i want to knw is that what is the difference between these different approaches
If I can put the data in session using HttpSession then
why we r provided with getSessionMap..... ??
Any considerable difference anyone of u noticed???

Comment: They're all different methods of putting stuff in the same holding area: the current http session. No tangible difference

Comment: yeah, this is what I was trying to figure out. Any other useful information/ suggestion related to this would be appreciable.

Comment: The JSF way is using a `@SessionScoped` bean. If you just need selective info, narrow your bean's properties, just think of it as a session map.